# How to combine multiple strings into one by using `=+` operator? - Java

Tags: java

I have a set of strings in an ArrayList and an empty String variable:

```
String combination;

ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
sList.add("H");
sList.add("e");
sList.add("l");
sList.add("l");
sList.add("o");
```

I am trying to combine all the letters so that it would print "Hello".

I tried using a for loop like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < sList.size(); x++) {

    combination =+ sList.get(x);
}
```

But when I try to compile this, it says:
`error: bad operand type String for unary operator '+++'`

How can I combine these letters with a loop?

(Note that the size of `sList` may change)

Comment: That'll be `+=`, not `=+`.

Comment: Have you tried `combination = combination + sList.get(x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `combination =+ sList.get(x);` to `combination +=sList.get(x);` or do `combination =combination+sList.get(x);`

Comment: One of the rules around here is that problems caused by typographical errors (such as `=+` instead of `+=`) are off topic, and should be closed, not answered.  I'm not sure whether your reputation score is enough yet to be able to vote for the closure of a question.  With any luck, you'll get there soon.

Comment: I can't vote yet.

Comment: Never mind.  If you keep on answering on-topic questions, you'll get there before too long.  It's disappointing that somebody downvoted this answer though - to me, that just seems mean.

Comment: the error doesn't ends here you need to *initialize* string too

Answer (score 2):

there are two errors out of one is already pointed by others which is typographical error and second error here is you haven't initialized string Bellow are two possible solutions

```
String combination = "";

        ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sList.add("H");
        sList.add("e");
        sList.add("l");
        sList.add("l");
        sList.add("o");

        for (int x = 0; x < sList.size(); x++) {
            combination += sList.get(x);

        }
        System.out.println(combination);

           ---------------------OR------------------------------
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(sList.size());
        for (String str : sList) {
            buffer.append(str);
        }

        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

just keep note that strings are immutable so they are returning new object every time and you can also use stringbuilder/stringbuffer which is recommended for string concatenation and both print statement product same result.

Comment: That's a little bit complicated, to me it works perfectly fine without using the StringBuffer class.

Comment: @TaeHyun.A you really should use the StringBuffer approach, performance matters!

Comment: @AsteriskNinja the StringBuffer can already be initialized with sList.size()